# Is it possible not to show to public your real name on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy, facebook-profile

I have to sign up with my real first, last names but do I have to show them to public on Facebook? Is there way to not let people see your real identity, may be separate public page or something? And if yes, could I use any nickname I want as my public name or should it be something similar, are initials allowed (Michael S.)?